# Missing 'Input format'

Tags: input-formats

On my inherited Drupal 6 site when I go to edit or add a news story 'Input format' is available for the Teaser, but not for the Body. I would like it for both or if it can only for one, have it on the Body so that I can choose an option such as 'Full HTML' so that images display. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked the settings on the body field?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

check your CKeditor settings in the following path:

*yoursitename*/admin/settings/ckeditor/editg

If you find anything related to this

**"*your content type*@node/add/*your content type*.edit-body"** in the "Fields to exclude/include: " textarea, just remove.